# SMS-MMS Class Unexpected Results

Tags: java, android, sms, mms

I am having some issues with this sms-mms class, the issue is it returns 6x the data expected. It displays 3 of the previous messages and then 3 of the current, I just need the 1 current and am unsure how I am ending up with the 6...Like so;

V/Debug: Observer Started

V/Debug: Received SMS

V/Debug: From: +15555551212

V/Debug: Type: 1

V/Debug: Time: Fri Feb 09 10:01:53 EST 2018

V/Debug: Body: some text message...

Rebuilt Class Source

```
public class MessageService extends Service {

private static final String VER = "1.1.10";
private static final String TAG = "ClassMessageService";

private ContentResolver contentResolver;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.v(TAG, "Message capturing service version: " + VER);
    Log.v(TAG, "Message capturing service created " + ReturnCurrentDateTime());

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    registerObserver();

    return START_STICKY;

}

public void registerObserver() {

    contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms"), true, new MessageObserver(new Handler()));

}

public String ReturnCurrentDateTime() {

    Date datetime = new Date();
    datetime.getTime();

    return datetime.toString();

}

class MessageObserver extends ContentObserver {

    private final UriMatcher MATCHER = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

    private static final int SMS_MESSAGE = 0;
    private static final int MMS_MESSAGE = 1;

    //static {
    //    MATCHER.addURI("sms", "#", SMS_MESSAGE);
    //    MATCHER.addURI("mms", "#", MMS_MESSAGE);
    //}

    public MessageObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        Log.v(TAG, "MessageObserver...");
        MATCHER.addURI("sms", "#", SMS_MESSAGE);
        MATCHER.addURI("mms", "#", MMS_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {

        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);

        switch (MATCHER.match(uri)) {
            case SMS_MESSAGE:

                Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToNext();

                String msg_id;
                String phone;
                String dateVal;
                String body;
                Date date;

                msg_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
                dateVal = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
                body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));

                date = new Date(Long.valueOf(dateVal));

                Log.v(TAG, "SMS: " + phone + " " + body + " " + msg_id + " " + date);

                break;

            case MMS_MESSAGE:

                Cursor mcursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                mcursor.moveToNext();

                String mmsg_id;
                String mphone;
                String mdateVal;
                String mbody;
                Date mdate;

                mmsg_id = mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                mphone = mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
                mdateVal = mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
                mbody = mcursor.getString(mcursor.getColumnIndex("body"));

                mdate = new Date(Long.valueOf(mdateVal));

                Log.v(TAG, "SMS: " + mphone + " " + mbody + " " + mmsg_id + " " + mdate);

                break;

            default:

        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Which Android version are you currently testing on? And what's the minimum version you plan on supporting? `ContentObserver`s on the messaging Providers have always been kind of a cluster, and the behavior has changed through the versions, so I wanna make sure I cover everything pertinent to your situation. Also, I assume you're registering your Observer on the `content://mms-sms` URI, yeah?

Comment: The API Versions are Max: 26 (Android 8.0 Oreo) Min: 17 (Android 4.2 Jelly Bean). To answer your question about registering Observer, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registering your `ContentObserver` on the `content://mms-sms` URI – presumably with `true` for descendants – will often get you a lot of redundant and irrelevant change notifications, and your Observer is reacting to all of them.

Both the standard `SmsProvider` and `MmsProvider` dispatch change notifications to multiple URIs. For example, the standard `SmsProvider` dispatches to the specific `content://sms/#` URI (where `#` is the message ID), as well as the general `content://mms-sms` URI, and the `content://mms-sms/conversation` URI. That's at least two notifications per message that your Observer is acting on.

Additionally, the `MmsSmsProvider` – which handles threads (conversations) in general, rather than individual messages – can fire change notifications on `content://mms-sms` whenever it modifies a thread; e.g., to update its summary, to mark it as read, etc. If you really only want to track message sends or receipts, these changes are irrelevant, but your Observer is still grabbing and processing the most recent message each time.

The solution I would recommend is two-part: alter your `ContentObserver` to override the `onChange(boolean, Uri)` method instead, and register separately on the `content://sms` and `content://mms` URIs.

Firstly, `ContentObserver` has had an `onChange()` method with a `Uri` parameter since API level 16. That is:

```
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    ...
}
```

Alone, this change to your Observer won't help much, since the `Uri` you get there will likely be for a general URI – e.g., `content://mms-sms` or `content://mms-sms/conversation` – with no other identifying information.

This is addressed by the second suggestion – registering separately on `content://sms` and `content://mms`, rather than `content://mms-sms`. That is:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), ...);
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://mms"), ...);
```

Doing this will preclude your Observer from receiving irrelevant notifications on the `content://mms-sms` URIs, and you should get a more specific `Uri` in `onChange()`, of the form `content://sms/#` or `content://mms/#`, where `#` is the message's ID, a `long`. This `Uri` can be used to check whether the message is SMS or MMS, and whether it's a change that you're interested in, as the URIs for irrelevant changes – e.g., changes to the SMS `raw` table – should not match those forms.

If using a single Observer<sup>*</sup> for both registered `Uri`s, both of those checks can be handled at once, with the use of a `UriMatcher`. For example:

```
public class MessageObserver extends ContentObserver {

    private static final UriMatcher MATCHER = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    private static final int SMS_MESSAGE = 0;
    private static final int MMS_MESSAGE = 1;
    static {
        MATCHER.addURI("sms", "#", SMS_MESSAGE);
        MATCHER.addURI("mms", "#", MMS_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        switch (MATCHER.match(uri)) {
            case SMS_MESSAGE:

                break;

            case MMS_MESSAGE:

                break;

            default:

        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Furthermore, you can query directly with that specific `Uri` to obtain the details for the single message, rather than querying on the general `content://sms` and `content://mms` URIs, and getting every message in either Provider, only to inspect the first one.

Lastly, you might've noticed that I've qualified many statements here, saying "should", "likely", etc. There are implementations of these Providers out there that can behave quite differently than expected. I would suggest that you test your Observer as thoroughly as possible.

---

<sup>* As far as I know, there is no issue with registering a single Observer instance for multiple URIs, and my tests have never had any problems. However, you can certainly implement separate `ContentObserver`s for SMS and MMS, and a `UriMatcher` could still be useful in filtering irrelevant URIs.</sup>

Comment: I rebuilt my class but am having trouble getting anything from it now, let me know what you think please.

Comment: First thing I see is that you're still registering on `content://mms-sms`. That `UriMatcher` and `switch` are going to filter any change notifications on that URI. (If you put a log print in the `default`, you should see something there.) When I said to register separately, I meant you'd have two `registerContentObserver()` calls, one with `Uri.parse("content://sms")`, and the other with `Uri.parse("content://mms")`. Follow me?

Comment: I also get a syntax error on the static {MATCHER.addURI("sms", "#", SMS_MESSAGE);} static not allowed on inner class...

Comment: Yeah, that's 'cause you nested that class inside the `Service`. No biggie. My example was in a separate, top-level class, in its own file. Yours is just fine. You moved those lines to an appropriate spot.

Comment: I love you man! Thanks for the AWESOME explanation! It's working!

Comment: Excellent. That's good to hear. It actually took me a while to get all the info and phrasing into a coherent answer. :-) Feel free to let me know if you come across any issues with this implementation. It's been a bit since I've done this myself. Anyhoo, glad to help. Cheers!

Comment: How can I add "sent" messages to that switch? I added the 3rd Resolver and this as well MATCHER.addURI("sent", "#", SENT_SMS_MESSAGE);

Comment: The sent messages of each kind should still be firing the respective `case` that you already have. That is, a sent SMS should still enter the `case SMS_MESSAGE:`. You would need to check the `"type"` column in the `Cursor` to distinguish sent and received, like you had in your original code. If that `case` isn't running for sent SMS, for some reason, then put a `Log.v("Debug", uri.toString());` in the `default`, and see what the URI is, exactly.